# Running ZTV (ZVI) on ArcGIS Desktop for 3m high object?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

What tool in the spatial toolbox would you use to run a ZTV (ZVI)? or is there a better way of carrying this type of query out using ArcGIS 10?

Also what other information would I need to do this type of query?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "ZTV" or "ZVI"--these are not standard.  ("Zone of varying intensity"? "Zone of visual influence"?)

Comment: My guess for ZTV is Zones of Theoretical Visibility.

Comment: "ZTV" (Zone of Theoretical Visibility) and "ZVI" (Zone of Theoretical Influence) are commonly used terms in the UK consultancy environment, they refer to a Viewshed. The latter (ZVI) become more commonplace a few years ago as consultants were often picked up upon the fact that the object in question (e.g. wind turbine, solar farm, pilon etc) were not actually visible in the field from particular viewpoint(s), despite their status being "visible". These terms therefore became commonly used in reporting to cover one's back (ie. the object may be visible from the observer location).

Answer (score 2):

The [comment above](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62803/how-to-run-a-ztv-zvi-on-esri-arcgis-10-for-a-3m-high-object#comment87538_62813) is incorrect. For work relating to environmental statements - ie for a windfarm OFFSETA needs to be the tip height of the turbine and OFFSETB is the height of the observer (general input of 2m). This is because you want to know if you were standing anywhere within a given radius of the wind farm would you see them. Hence you want to know where (standing at a height of 2m) can I see a wind turbine (100m).

OFFSETA is the observation points which is the height of the turbines as these are the points being observed.
OFFSETB is the z-value of each cell being considered for visibility which you would want to be 2m above the elevation model.

This is an easy mistake to make and form the output from the process it will not be obvious that you have done it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

A brief search seems to indicate that ZTV is what a viewshed is called in the UK, so I'm going with that.

You will need to use the Viewshed tool in the 3D Analyst extension.

You need to add the OFFSETA field with your offset value to your observer point(s).

> When the observer features dataset is a point feature class, each
>   observation point can have a unique set of observation constraints in
>   the attribute table. When it is a polyline feature class, every vertex
>   along an input polyline uses the same observation constraints
>   contained in the polyline's record in the attribute table.
>
> The definitions for these items can vary as long as they are numeric.
>   Whenever an item does not exist, the default values are applied.
>
> SPOT: The SPOT item is used to define the surface elevations for the
>   observation points.
>
> Offset: The offset is the vertical distance (in surface units) to be
>   added to the z-value of a location on the surface.
>
> There are two offset items, one defining the elevation to be added to
>   the observer location and the other defining what will be added to
>   each cell to be considered for visibility.
>
> OFFSETA: The OFFSETA item indicates a vertical distance in surface
>   units to be added to the z-value of the observation point.
>
> If OFFSETA exists in the feature attribute table, its value is added
>   to the SPOT elevation when present; otherwise, it is added to the
>   interpolated surface z-value. The OFFSETA value must be positive. If
>   the OFFSETA item does not exist, the default value is 1.

From here: [ArcGIS Viewshed](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Performing_visibility_analysis_with_Viewshed_and_Observer_Points/009z000000v8000000/)

Comment: The above is correct. Add a field named "OFFSETA" (to store the observer elevations). Typically a 'worst-case' is used for Environmental Statements or Landscape and Visual Impact Assessment analyses, so an observer height of 2 metres is selected. You may also like to add another field named "OFFSETB" to store the elevations of the object to be observed (i.e. a wind turbine, solar farm, pylon or bridge etc). Both functions uniformly increase the Z-value attribute from the elevation model.